# what is the purpose of this property"es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors" and its benefit in elasticsearch. How should i use it

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

what is the purpose of

> es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors = false/true

i just want to know ,what are the benefits ,how can i use it.

Please share your knowledge if any one knows.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/NettyRuntime.html#availableProcessors--
It's not a true/false but a positive int that overrides the represented number processors available.

Some netty internals are sized according to the number of available processors (like thread pools). Sometimes, for testing purposes, it is useful to modify the number of processors which is then passed on to the underlying configuration. In some cases, when running in containers such as Kubernetes, the reported number of processors is not optimal, so this feature also serves to adjust that.

Comment: In elastic i made it false so that it couldn't  take default  number of processor. I just want look it from elasticsearch  perspective. As this feature  was not present in version <5.4.

Comment: I was added to allow to set the number of cores and so size stuff accordantly. Mostly its useful for VM / containers where you may see more cores then the actual ones that you want to reserve

Answer (score 0):

Well i got some comments from elasticsearch  team. They are using it for running up their own test cases.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/need-info-for-es-set-netty-runtime-available-processors/111322/4?u=antitech